# How to require 1 model variable value before submission of another variable

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Hostel Booking system:

```
public class Booking(){
   public int Adults { get; set; }
   public int Children { get; set; }
   ...
}
```

i want to have the Create.cshtml view so that for any number of children, at least 1 adult is required. a booking can have as many adults, but requires at least 1 adult for 1 or more children to be booked

is there a data annotation that i can use on the children variable to require at least 1 adult?

thanks

Comment: you shouldn't have to do anything with children,  just put required on the adults

Comment: Wouldn't you use data range on Adults, since 0 is a valid value of Required and is also the default value of int?

Comment: thanks very much guys, using either required or range worked fine

Answer (score -1):

Create the Booking Constructor with a new Adult.

```
public class Booking(){
   public int Adults { get; set; }
   public int Children { get; set; }
   public Booking(){
     Adult = new Adult();
   }
}
```

Comment: He has a count of adults not an adult object.